# How can i use generated elements from one emf model in another generated editor

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, emf, ecore

For example:

**Model 1:**

```
abstract class Command{}
```

**Model 2:**

```
class Command1 extends Command{ ...}
class Command2 extends Command{ ...}
```

**Model 3:**

```
class CommandHolder {
 val Command[+] commands;
}
```

Now i generate the Editor to Model3 and want Command1 and Command2 to become selectable as children of the CommandHolder Element.

This means, if i create a  CommandHolder File with the commands element as root element and make a right click on it and select [New Child] i would like Command1 and Command2 to appear in this list.

Is this possible without changing the generated source code?

Greetings

Comment: So you're trying to extend one EMF model with another and have the results of generating from both models work with each other?

Comment: Yes i want the Model 3 Editor to show the Model 2 Elements as choosable children in the treeeditor menu for the Commands-Element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i could not realize it without changing the generated code but i have a working solution.

In the specific item provider in the collectNewChildDescriptors Method from the CommandHolder i added

```
 List<EClass> cmdClasses = EcoreHelper.getAllClassesInheritFrom("Command");
    for(EClass cmdClass : cmdClasses){
        newChildDescriptors.add
        (createChildParameter
            (CommandPackage.Literals.COMMAND__COMMANDS,
             EcoreHelper.createClassByName(cmdClass.getName())));
    }
```

The EcoreHelper Methods:

```
public static EObject createClassByName(String className) {

        EObject eObject = null;
        try {
            Registry registry = EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE;
            for (String key : new HashSet<String>(registry.keySet())) {
            EPackage ePackage = registry.getEPackage(key);
            if (ePackage.getClass().getName().startsWith("")) {
                for (EClassifier eClassifier : ePackage.getEClassifiers()) {
                if (eClassifier instanceof EClass) {
                    EClass eClass = (EClass) eClassifier;
                    if (eClass.getName().equals(className)) {
                    if (!eClass.isAbstract()) {
                        eObject = ePackage.getEFactoryInstance().create(eClass);
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return eObject;
        }


 public static List<EClass> getAllClassesInheritFrom(String className) {
        List<EClass> eClasses = new ArrayList<EClass>();
        try {
            Registry registry = EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE;
            for (String key : new HashSet<String>(registry.keySet())) {
            EPackage ePackage = registry.getEPackage(key);
            if (ePackage.getClass().getName().startsWith("")) {
                for (EClassifier eClassifier : ePackage.getEClassifiers()) {
                if (eClassifier instanceof EClass) {
                    EClass eClass = (EClass) eClassifier;
                    if (eClass.getName().equals(className)) {
                    if (!eClass.isAbstract()) {
                        eClasses.add(eClass);

                    }
                    } else {
                    for (EClass bla : eClass.getEAllSuperTypes()) {
                        if (bla.getName().equals(className)) {
                        if (!eClass.isAbstract()) {
                            eClasses.add(eClass);
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return eClasses;
        }
```